# What's the fastest way in Ruby to get the first enumerable element for which a block returns true?

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

What's the fastest way in Ruby to get the first enumerable element for which a block returns true?

For example:

```
arr = [12, 88, 107, 500]
arr.select {|num| num > 100 }.first  # => 107
```

I'd like to do this without running through the entire array, as `select` will, since I only need the first match.

I know I could do an `each` and break on success, but I thought there was a native method for doing this; I just haven't found it in the documentation.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Several core ruby classes, including `Array` and `Hash` include the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html) module which provides many useful methods to work with these enumerations.

This module provides the [`find` or `detect` methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) which do exactly what you want to achieve:

```
arr = [12, 88, 107, 500]
arr.find { |num| num > 100 } # => 107
```

Both method names are synonyms to each other and do exactly the same.

Comment: Ah! `find` was the method I was trying to remember. Silly me, I was looking at the docs for `Array`, not `Enumerable`.

Comment: also known in the Ruby world as `detect`

Comment: All hail to the synonyms. I personally prefer `find` (even more so when I'm not in a Rails environment). But you are are right, it might be better to generally use `detect` to un-confuse people.

Comment: Update - I always use the `detect` alias for this now. It's easy for me to remember `select reject detect` and doesn't get confused with ActiveRecord's `find`.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.find{|el| el>100} #107 (or detect; it's in the Enumerable module.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember this using by thinking of ActiveRecord.find, which gets you the first record and ActiveRecord.select, which you use when you're getting all of them.

Not a perfect comparison but might be enough to help remember.